# Array already dimentioned/subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

If I set an array as dynamic, I get a `subscript out of range` error. If I set it as static, I get an `array already dimentioned` error. What am I missing?

```
Dim arrTrips() As String 'dynamic
Dim arrTrips(1 To 99) As String 'static
...
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If .Cells(i, "C").Value2 = Target.Value2 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrTrips(UBound(arrTrips) + 1) <-- error here
        arrTrips(UBound(arrTrips)) = .Cells(i, "M").Value2
        Debug.Print arrTrips(UBound(arrTrips))
    End If
Next
```

Edit: adding more context. I am adding items to the array inside a loop.

LOL I fixed it. It's so stupid. All I did was add `ReDim arrTrips(1) As String` right below `Dim arrTrips() As String`

Comment: when you do `DimArrTrips() as String` you're creating an empty array. It doesn't have a `UBound`. You *can* `ReDim Preserve` it, but you have to use an expression that doesn't derive from the array's bounds.

Comment: @DavidZemens so something like `ReDim Preserve arrTrips(1)`? Edit: doesn't that just delay the issue? I am adding items to the array so I have to `redim` it to a `ubound` at some point?

Comment: You're not getting the same issue each time. One raises the index error, the other won't compile because you can't `ReDim Preserve` the array that was initialized with `(1 to 99)`.

Comment: If it's the first time you `ReDim` the array (and you've not assigned any values in the array), then you don't need the `Preserve` keyword, just `ReDim arrTrips(1 To 1)` or `ReDim arrTrips(1 To 15)`. But the array should be dimensionless in order to use `ReDim` I believe.

Comment: @PeterT how will that work with a loop on the next iteration?

Comment: Arrays default to base 0, so when you `ReDim` or `Dim` it with a base 1, I think you need to also `ReDim Preserve arrTrips(1 to UBound...)`

Comment: Basically after I declare variable, I redim it so it can have a `ubound` then I can `redim preserve` it later. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you're intializing an empty array, the `Ubound` function fails on that. There is no built-in method to test whether an array is "empty" so you need to either use error-trapping or a UDF that encapsulates error-trapping in order to determine whether the array has no dimensions.

Alternatively, since you know at the onset that the array is empty, you can simply `ReDim` it to *something*, and then you can later `ReDim Preserve` it within your loop.

```
Sub staticArra()
Dim arrTrips() As String
ReDim arrTrips(1 To 1) As String

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    ReDim Preserve arrTrips(LBound(arrTrips) To UBound(arrTrips) + 1) As String
Next
End Sub
```

The second one, using `ReDim arrTrips(1 to 99)` fails to compile, by design.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement

> The `ReDim` statement is used to size or resize a dynamic array that has already been formally declared by using a `Private`, `Public`, or `Dim` statement with empty parentheses (without dimension subscripts).

But the ideal approach (in terms of conserving lines & avoiding redundant calls) would be to instantiate your array using `ReDim` instead of `Dim`, with a subscript. You can `ReDim Preserve` this:

```
Sub f()
ReDim arrTrips(0) As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    If (i - 1) > UBound(arrTrips) Then
        ReDim Preserve arrTrips(i)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

In short: give your array an upper bound to begin with.

Comment: Yea, it's kinda stupid in that it's wholly redundant. Why not just give it a `ubound` to begin with?? `ReDim arrTrips(1 To 1) As String` is a waste of code -_-

Comment: Eh. It's just the way it's always been. There are hundreds of discussions/threads on this exact error on various forums over the past 15 years or so :) but it would've made sense IMO to return a -1 if the array has no items in it or some other built-in way of determining that the array is empty. But you have to use UDF for that. Chip Pearson has a bunch of neat helper functions for dealing with arrays: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm

Comment: @findwindow you can avoid the redundancy if you initialize the array using `ReDim` with subscript, instead of `Dim`, see revised answer :)

Comment: "It's just the way it's always been" There would be no cars, planes or computers if we went by that logic. Ah nice, now I know to just `redim` to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

**Declaration 1**

```
Dim arrTrips() As String
```

This is dynamic but its empty. When you do a Ubound on this, compiler will not find a size and will throw an error. Below will work since it is not derived from your arrTrips array

```
ReDim Preserve arrTrips(10)
```

Declaration 2:

```
Dim arrTrips(1 To 99) As String
```

This being static array, it can only be dimensioned once and will throw an error if you try to redimesion it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter:

```
Dim arrTrips() As String

...
Dim k As Long
k = 1
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If .Cells(i, "C").Value2 = Target.Value2 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrTrips(1 to k)
        arrTrips(k) = .Cells(i, "M").Value2
        Debug.Print arrTrips(k)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next
```

---

You can also use COUNTIF to set the size of the array before the loop:

```
Dim arrTrips() As String

...

Dim k As Long
k = Application.CountIf(.Range("C:C"), Target.Value2)
ReDim arrTrips(1 To k)

Dim j As Long
j = 1
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If .Cells(i, "C").Value2 = Target.Value2 Then
        arrTrips(j) = .Cells(i, "M").Value2
        Debug.Print arrTrips(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This makes more sense to me. There is no "wasted" code.